# jQuery - Dialog Box using .closest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pop a dialog box open using .closest but I can't seem to make it work.

**I've fiddled it here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dx2yz8mg/

```
$(function(){
    $('.prdDetails').click(function() {
        $('#prdDetails').dialog({
            draggable: false,
            height: 430,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 774,
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**I've tried this :**

```
$(this).closest('#prdDetails').dialog({
```

I feel like this is okay but it doesn't work, does anybody have any ideas?

The reason I need to do it this way is I'm pulling in content dynamically.  Currently when you click the second .prdDetails you see the first #prdDetails in the popup.

Comment: use `$(this).siblings('#prdDetails')`

Comment: You've misunderstood what `.closest()` does. Read here http://api.jquery.com/closest/ but in your fiddle you may want to target the ID directly since ID's are unique elements.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand what [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) does. It goes **up** the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that you should use *next* instead of *closest*,

```
   $(this).next('#prdDetails').dialog({
```

next will find the immediate next sibling, while closest searches up the DOM tree.

You should also remove the multiple IDs, and check if you have already created a dialog to avoid instantiating it on each click, something. like this should be a complete solution

http://jsfiddle.net/dx2yz8mg/7/

Comment: Thanks, this works as I wanted on the first run.  But after that subsequent clicks don't work.  I've refiddled it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dx2yz8mg/4/  Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited the fiddle, should be working for you now

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), `.closest` checks the element itself and traverses up the DOM.

You have this:

```
<a class="prdDetails">More Details ></a>
<div id="prdDetails" class="hidden">Stuff</div>
```

They are siblings, not parent/childs.

BTW, you should use `&gt;` instead of `>`

Answer (score -1):

You have `width: 774,` You have to remove the `,` behind `width`